# Visually undestanding weighed information

Tags: probability, logarithms, information-theory

**Background**

Both Shannon and Boltzmann used a common mathematical formula to define a new quantity known as entropy. The formula is:

$$ {\large\displaystyle \mathrm {H} (X)=-\sum _{i=1}^{n}{\mathrm {P} (x_{i})\log _{b}\mathrm {P} (x_{i})}} $$

I am a visual learner. The interpretation of the `information` $\log _{b}\mathrm {P} (x_{i})$ is nice and simple: it is the height in a tree of shape b. Non integers results are a sort of mental extension of it ( cant think of a representation ).

**Question**

Is there any visual or intuitive way to look at $\large\mathrm{H(x)}$?

Comment: Not a visual interpretation, but you can think of entropy as the average number of digits (in base $b$) you will need to encode an outcome from the distribution (under an optimal encoding). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory) or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5c_RFKVkko&t=593s

Comment: Im reading this article https://plus.maths.org/content/information-surprise seems quite intuitive. I will look at Wp too. Thanks @Anakhand

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense. Thank  you! @Anakhand